# Android Studio File Structure

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to group methods in my class, but it is proving very difficult to navigate as the file structure appears to only show all items alphabetically. Is there a way to view a file's content;s in the order in which items appear, rather than alphabetically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the top toolbar of the Structure tool window, the first two buttons control the sort order. The first button sorts by visibility and the second sorts alphabetically. Ensure that BOTH are **unchecked** in order to view the structure in the order in which items appear.

Comment: Uh, not exactly. Works for methods.  But this window seems to always list classes first, even if they are last.  I usually define sub-classes at the end, but this list always lists them first.